# How do late static bindings work in this scenario?

Tags: php, php-5.3

The following code outputs 'x as set in class A', how would I make it output 'x as set in class B' without changing class B?

```
<?php

class A
{
    public static $x = 'x as set in class A';

    public static function getX()
    {
        return self::$x;
    }
}


class B extends A
{
    public static $x = 'x as set in class B';
}


echo B::getX();
```

Comment: Just for the record, this is NOT what I asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self` *always* refers to the class, where it is defined. What you are looking for is "Late Static Binding" (as you already suggest, but dont use). The `static` keyword within a code block refers to the "actual" class, means: Either the called class (`XY::method()`), or the class of the called object (`$x->method()`).

```
return static::$x;
```

The `static` keyword at the property declaration has nothing to to with LSB. It is just the common declartion for class properties.

Note, that LSB is not available in PHP<5.3